# NPOI in unity missing enumeration value 'vstream' error

Tags: c#, excel, unity-game-engine, npoi

I have built a non gaming Unity application which is using NPOI to import and populate a SQLite DB from an XLSX Excel file. This works fine. Now what i need to do is output an Excel file but when I try to create it i get the below exception on the following line of code:

```
IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

This is the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Type NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.ItemChoiceType is missing enumeration value 'vstream' for element 'vstream from
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElementInfo
>   (System.Type cls, System.String defaultName, System.String
>   defaultNamespace, System.Type defaultType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMemberElement member,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember
>   (System.Type declaringType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting field 'Item'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_Property'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root,
>   System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElementInfo
>   (System.Type cls, System.String defaultName, System.String
>   defaultNamespace, System.Type defaultType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapMemberElement member,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes atts)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateMapMember
>   (System.Type declaringType,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionMember rmember, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting field 'property'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportClassMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace) Rethrow as InvalidOperationException: There was an
>   error reflecting type 'NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CT_CustomProperties'.
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root, System.String
>   defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping
>   (System.Type type, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute root,
>   System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type,
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides overrides,
>   System.Type[] extraTypes, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute
>   root, System.String defaultNamespace)
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor (System.Type type)
>   NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CustomPropertiesDocument..cctor () (at
>   C:/Users/seadn/Desktop/npoi/npoi-master/ooxml/OpenXmlFormats/CustomPropertiesDocument.cs:9)
>   Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.CustomPropertiesDocument
>   NPOI.POIXMLProperties..cctor () Rethrow as
>   TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type
>   initializer for NPOI.POIXMLProperties
>   NPOI.POIXMLDocument.GetProperties () Rethrow as POIXMLException
>   NPOI.POIXMLDocument.GetProperties ()
>   NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook.OnWorkbookCreate ()
>   NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook..ctor () Admin.ExportExcel () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Asset Manager/Admin.cs:465)
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:165)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:58)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick
>   (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:45)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler
>   handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler]
>   (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData
>   eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

I have looked into the class in the npoi code and found the vStream
enum on lines 442, 443 in DocumentPropertiesCustom.cs so I'm pretty
confused that it can't find it. Also I'm not familiar with npoi.

Any help is certainly much appreciated!